# How can I make a graph of a website in python?

Tags: python, graph, python-2.7

I would like to make a python script which take as an input primary url for example:
https://stackoverflow.com/ 
and then it goes recursivley over all the pages and make a directed graph of all the pages (nodes) of the site and its sub pages, which has an edged if and only if there is link in node a (page a) to node b (page b). I assume there is something like that but I didn't find in google... If there is any ideas, maybe using `wget` who something else I would love to hear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll only give you pointers to what you'll need to build such a tool using basic python :

- First you will need [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) to open urls .
- Then, you can either use [regexps](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) or [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to find links in your pages. The first one is less CPU-expensive, but less precise, the latter is a fuzzy HTML parser (meaning that it accepts defective HTML)
- You can then store your URLs in a `list` of urls to crawl, and for each link you find in a page, you will need to check if you already crawled it (to avoid infinite cycles), using a `set`
- To build your graph, for each new page you crawl, it's a new node. Each link you find is a new edge.

Or, you can use [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/), a python library made for crawling.

Comment: Great answer - might be more complete if you fill in the last part of the answer, drawing the graph. For that I'd use `networkx` or a wrapper to `graphviz` (e.g. `pydot` and the like).

Comment: It was not clear if it was to draw the graph, or just build it. But your additions are definitively worthwhile. Thanks !